# How can I assign the results of multiple JS function invocations to a PHP array?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

1.I have JS function that creates HTML array 
2.This function is called multiple times , therefore multiple arrays are created too 
3.How can I assign all created HTML arrays as keys of a new PHP array ?

var nextId = 0;

function addLanguage()
{

```
nextId++;

var inputDiv = document.createElement("div");

inputDiv.setAttribute("id","num" + nextId);

inputDiv.innerHTML = 
    "<input type='text' name='langs[]'/>"
    +
    "<select name='langs[]'>\n\
        <option value='comprehension'>-comprehension-</option>\n\
        <option value='beginner'>beginner</option>\n\
        <option value='intermediate'>intermediate</option>\n\
        <option value='advanced'>advanced</option>\n\
    </select>"
    +
    "<select name='langs[]'>\n\
        <option value='reading'>-reading-</option>\n\
        <option value='beginner'>beginner</option>\n\
        <option value='intermediate'>intermediate</option>\n\
        <option value='advanced'>advanced</option>\n\
    </select>"
    +
    "<select name='langs[]'>\n\
        <option value='writing'>-writing-</option>\n\
        <option value='beginner'>beginner</option>\n\
        <option value='intermediate'>intermediate</option>\n\
        <option value='advanced'>advanced</option>\n\
    </select><br>"
    +
    "<input type='button' value='Remove Language' onclick='removeLanguage(\"num" + nextId + "\")'>"
    +
    "<button type='button' value='press' onclick='addLanguage()'>Add Language</button>"
    ;

        document.getElementById('langs').appendChild(inputDiv);
```

}

So addLanguage() is called multiple times and creates multiple langs[] array . How can I assign these arrays as keys to another array ?

Comment: Do you have any source code to go with your question?  I hope so because as your questions stands at this moment in time I find it very unclear what you're asking or wish to achieve, also... what have you tried?

Comment: show your code please

Comment: Any recommendation ?